# How do I set up my Django urlpatterns within my app (not project)

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

Let's say I've got the classic "School" app within my Django project.  My `school/models.py` contains models for both `student` and `course`. All my project files live within a directory I named `config`.

How do I write an include statement(s) within `config/urls.py` that references two separate endpoints within `school/urls.py`?  And then what do I put in `schools/urls.py`?

For example, if I were trying to define an endpoint just for `students`, in `config/urls.py` I would do something like this:

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("students/", include("school.urls"), name="students"),
    ...
]
```

And then in `school/urls.py` I would do something like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from peakbagger.views import StudentCreateView, StudentDetailView, StudentListView, StudentUpdateView, StudentDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("", StudentListView.as_view(), name="student-list"),
    path("add/", StudentCreateView.as_view(), name="student-add"),
    path("<int:pk>/", StudentDetailView.as_view(), name="student-detail"),
    path("<int:pk>/update/", StudentUpdateView.as_view(), name="student-update"),
    path("<int:pk>/delete/", StudentDeleteView.as_view(), name="student-delete"),
]
```

But how do I do I add another urlpattern to config/urls.py along the lines of something like this?  The `include` statement needs some additional info/parameters, no?

```
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("students/", include("school.urls"), name="students"),
    path("courses/", include("school.urls"), name="courses"),
    ...
]
```

And then what happens inside of `school/urls.py`?

I'm open to suggestions, and definitely am a neophyte when it comes to the Django philosophy.  Do I need an additional urls.py somewhere?  I'd prefer not to put everything in `config/urls.py` and I'd prefer not to build a separate app for both students and courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather create two (or more) `urls.py` files and then point them separately.

```
# directory structure
school/
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── __init__.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── tests.py
├── urls
│   ├── course.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── student.py
└── views.py


# school/urls/course.py
from django.urls import path
from school.views import CourseListView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", CourseListView.as_view(), name="course_list"),
    # other URLs
]



# school/urls/student.py
from django.urls import path
from school.views import StudentListView

urlpatterns = [
    path("", StudentListView.as_view(), name="student_list"),
    # other URLs
]


# config/urls.py
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("student/", include("school.urls.student")),
    path("course/", include("school.urls.course")),
    # other URLs
]
```

Comment: While the other answer is also valid, I chose this one because it keeps both subdirectory redirects in `config/urls.py`, which was part of my design problem (albeit I could have perhaps worded it more explicitly there).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you is to make separate urls directory inside your app
For example if  you have school as app then
app

```
├── School
│   ├── views.py
│   └── models.py
|   └── urls
|       └── __init__.py
|       └── urls.py
|       └── school_urls.py
|       └── course_urls.py
```

Now in your main project urls you can set this way

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("", include("school.urls"), name="students"),
    ...
]
```

and in urls.py of your school urls folder you can do this way

```
    urlpatterns = [
        ...
        path("students/", include("school.urls.school_urls"), name="students"),
 path("course/", include("school.urls.course_urls"), name="course"),
        ...
    ]
```

and you can do add course view in course url folder and another student view in student urls file